# CPU usage by CPU component

Tags: cpu, performance, cpu-usage, cpu-architecture

CPUs are made up of multiple components, such as the ALU and CU. Hyper-threading allows multiple threads to run conconcurrently where there's available resource in these components. On a single core CPU, with hyperthreading, presumably if one hyper-thread is using all of the available resources of part of the CPU the performing SIMD instructions, then it'll block the other hyper-thread from the same component.

I'm interested in viewing usage by these different components, specifically the usage of the component that's executing SIMD instructions. How can I do this?

Comment: OS not specified. Doesn't it matter?

Comment: I'd be interested in any operating system, just to see how it could be done. But I would be more interested in Windows XP specifically.